# Por que para se candidatar é apenas 300 pontos?

Tags: debate, eleição

Vi que para se candidatar a moderador é necessario apenas **300** pontos de reputação, mas na parte de **pontuação do candidato -/-**, o "máximo" é **20k** de reputação(depois disse ele mostra: reputação >= 20k).

Tem uma diferença muito grande entre **20k** e **300**, então por que precisa de apenas **300** para se candidatar, não seria melhor colocar **1000** ou **500**(com 500 pois tem acesso as filas de analise).

Comment: Sobre mostrar `>= 20k`, acho que é porque o último privilégio relacionado a moderação é com 20 mil pontos de reputação: [Usuário Confiável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Comment: Ata, entendi, mas então por que para se candidatar a reputação necessaria é tão baixa?

Comment: Eu encontrei duas respostas do Shog9 (em inglês) sobre o assunto: uma no [meta do SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289523/8839059) e outra no [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139398/818993). Mas não posso confirmar se esse ainda é o pensamento para hoje.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Acho que outro fator é que a reputação é usada no cálculo da pontuação do candidato: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/401803 (1 ponto para 1000 rep, sendo 20K o limite máximo). Então se a pessoa tiver 20K ou 10000K, não fará diferença para o cálculo...